# C++ How to write function that return char pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I want to write a function that receive an int argument then converter to a char pointer (c-string), but my code output is not right.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
char *stoc(int n){
    stringstream stream;
    stream <<"Log"<<n<<".txt";
    string name;
    stream >>name;
    int len = name.length();

    char ch[len+1];
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        ch[i]=name[i];

    }
    ch[len+1] = '\0';

    return ch;
}

int main() {
    char *name = stoc(3);
    cout << name << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C++, you don't do that. Use `std::string` please, and no VLAs.

Comment: Two problems: First of all C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Secondly and much worse, you return a pointer to an array that will go out of scope and disappear once the function returns.

Comment: Oh and you go out of bounds of the `ch` array as well, with `ch[len+1] = '\0';` Strike three.

Comment: Why convert the `std::string` to a C-style-string anyway? Just return `name` instead of `ch`. If you do need to convert them you can still later use [`std::string::c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) instead.

Comment: Lastly, if you change the function to return a `std::string`, it could be converted into a one-liner: `return "Log" + std::to_string(n) + ".txt";` Then if you for some reason need a `const char*` to the string, use [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Summarising the comments:

You normally do not use C-style-strings in C++, just stick to `std::string`s. Therefor you should rather return `name` instead of your converted `ch`, especially since you have already created a `std::string`. Having access to at least C++11 you can then easily convert your rather long function into a one-liner

*C++11*

```
std::string stoc(int n) {
  return "Log" + std::to_string(n) + ".txt";
}
```

*prior C++11*

```
std::string stoc(int n) {
  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss << "Log" + n + ".txt";
  return oss.str(); // by accessing a stringstreams content directly there is no need to use an extra variable
}
```

If you do need to use a C-style-string later on somewhere, e.g. as a parameter for a C-library function, you can use `c_str` to convert any `std::string` into it's C-style equivalent:

```
int main() {
    std::string name = stoc(3);
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this instead of returning a pointer to a local variable (which yields in undefined behaviour):

```
...
char *ch = new char[len+1];
for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
    ch[i]=name[i];
}
ch[len] = '\0';
...

int main() {
    char *name = stoc(3);
    cout << name << endl;
    delete [] name;   // delete what has been allocated in stoc

    return 0;
}
```

Also note the `ch[len] = '\0'` instead of `ch[len + 1] = '\0'`.

But in C++ you should rather use `std::string` and not deal with `char` arrays, `new` and `delete` at all.